# Featured Posts Section on Wordpress won't show up

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Trying to create a Featured Posts Section on my site and there are three files involved:

- header file
- footer file
- functions file
- index file

I want to make selecting a featured post is just by checking a checkbox in edit screen (posts page) AND be able to retrieve these featured articles on the front page.

So far with my current code it is showing up a checkbox only on the posts page edit screen however it won't save and on the front page nothing is appearing except the posts loop.

here's my functions.php file:

```
/**
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * 1.0 - Define constants.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

define( 'THEMEROOT', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
define( 'IMAGES', THEMEROOT. '/images' );
define( 'SCRIPTS', THEMEROOT. '/js' );

/** */


/***********************************************************************************************/
/* 2.0 - Add Theme Support for Post Thumbnails */
/***********************************************************************************************/
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    set_post_thumbnail_size(300, 200);

}



/***********************************************************************************************/
/* 3.0 - Add Theme Support for Post Thumbnails */
/***********************************************************************************************/


function register_post_assets(){
    add_meta_box('featured-post', __('Featured Post'), 'add_featured_meta_box', 'post', 'advanced', 'high');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'register_post_assets', 1);

function add_featured_meta_box($post){
    $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured-post', true);
    echo "<label for='_featured-post'>".__('Feature this post?', 'foobar')."</label>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='_featured-post' id='featured-post' value='1' ".checked(1, $featured)." />";
}

function save_featured_meta($post_id){
    // Do validation here for post_type, nonces, autosave, etc...
    if (isset($_REQUEST['featured-post']))
        update_post_meta(esc_attr($post_id, '_featured-post', esc_attr($_REQUEST['featured-post']))); 
        // I like using _ before my custom fields, so they are only editable within my form rather than the normal custom fields UI
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_featured_meta');


?>
```

Here's my code on the index.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="gray">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></h1>
          <p class="details">By <a href="<?php the_author_posts() ?>"><?php the_author(); ?> </a> / On <?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?> / In <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
          <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
          <figure> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'opacity-hover box-layer img-responsive')); ?></a> </figure>
          <p class="excerpt"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>
          <div class="btn-margin"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">CONTINUE READING >>> </a> </div>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>


<h1>Featured Posts</h1>     
<?php       
  $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'meta_key' => '_featured-post',
        'meta_value' => 1
    );

    $featured = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($featured->have_posts()): while($featured->have_posts()): $featured->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile; else:

    endif;  
?>      

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any idea what's causing the problem or if I am missing something? I just want to have a featured posts section on my blog atleast similar to this image:

http://goo.gl/E5tbMv

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to check if the metadata is being saved?

Comment: Hi Tomas it is not saving at all actually. Can you check please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function add_featured_meta_box($post){
    $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_featured-post', true);
    echo "<label for='_featured-post'>".__('Feature this post?', 'foobar')."</label>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='featured-post' id='featured-post' value='1' ".checked(1, $featured)." />";
}

function save_featured_meta($post_id){
    // Do validation here for post_type, nonces, autosave, etc...
    if (isset($_REQUEST['featured-post']))
        update_post_meta(esc_attr($post_id), '_featured-post', esc_attr($_REQUEST['featured-post'])); 
        // I like using _ before my custom fields, so they are only editable within my form rather than the normal custom fields UI
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_featured_meta');
```

Try with that code, I corrected the `name`attribute and the `update_post_meta` function. Sorry but I currently don't have a Wordpress install to try it.

You seem to use the id `featured-post` twice, too. You should change the id of the `înput` field.

Comment: Thanks Tomas! It is now appearing! You are awesome!